# java regex until certain word/text/characters

Tags: java, regex

Please consider the following text :

```
That is, it matches at any position that has a non-word character to the left of it, and a word character to the right of it.
```

How can I get the following result :

```
That is, it matches at any position that has a non-word character to the
```

That is everything until `left`

Comment: How do these weak questions go unfilterred? The least that should be done is a specific real example, at least someone who doesen't know what a 'word' is will not get confused.

Comment: @sin How do these weak comments go unfiltered? The least that should be done is explain the confusion.

Comment: The problem with this question is using an example text which could itself be a part of the question text. As if there were no other sentences in the world.

Comment: I think it was supposed to be a lead in to what a word boundry is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
input.replace("^(.*?)\\bleft.*$", "$1");
```

- `^` anchors to the beginning of the string
- `.*?` matches as little as possible of any character
- `\b` matches a word boundary
- `left` matches the string literal `"left"`
- `.*` matches the remainder of the string
- `$` anchors to the end of the string
- `$1` replaces the matched string with group 1 in `()`

If you want to use any word (not just `"left"`), be careful to escape it. You can use `Pattern.quote(word)` to escape the string.

Comment: @London, it shouldn't have worked. Replace left with '-left' in the string and regex. Or is 'left' not variable text? So what worked about it?

Comment: @sin Please read the full answer before criticising it. I explain how to use a variable word at the end.

Comment: @sin If that is the case then you have to use a different boundary-matching (e.g. `?<=\s`) or forego it entirely. I put more weight on not matching `fooleft` than a non-word such as `-left`.

Comment: Yea, english is a funny thing, some would say a word is a character class, others would say its not -left as opposed to _left. Me, I don't put any weight on \b at all, never did.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually `/(.*)\Wleft\w/` but it won't match anything in

```
That is, it matches at any position that has a non-word character to the left of it, and a word character to the right of it.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = inputString.replace("(.*?)left.*", "$1");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the only flaw that might happen in this is if there are newlines that you didn't mention